# how to extract strong tags from a column in a dataframe and append or replace that cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns that has bold letters that i need to extract. there are 53000 rows and 27 columns that has strong bold letter.

```
array(['Candidate initial submission',
      'The Candidate Status has now been updated from <strong>CV Submitted</strong> and <strong>Feedback Pending</strong> to <strong>Client CV Review</strong> and <strong>Feedback Awaiting</strong>Candidate initial submission',
      'The Candidate Status has now been updated from <strong>CV Submitted</strong> and <strong>Feedback Pending</strong> to <strong>Interview 1</strong> and <strong>Scheduled</strong> with Stage Date 02 August, 2018, 12:00 am IST - UTC +05:30'],
     dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [pandas.Series.str.extractall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
import pandas as pd

lst = ['Candidate initial submission',
 'The Candidate Status has now been updated from <strong>CV Submitted</strong> and <strong>Feedback Pending</strong> to <strong>Client CV Review</strong> and <strong>Feedback Awaiting</strong>Candidate initial submission',
 'The Candidate Status has now been updated from <strong>CV Submitted</strong> and <strong>Feedback Pending</strong> to <strong>Interview 1</strong> and <strong>Scheduled</strong> with Stage Date 02 August, 2018, 12:00 am IST - UTC +05:30']


df = pd.DataFrame(data=lst, columns=['text'])

result = df.text.str.extractall('<strong>(.+?)</strong>')
```

**Output**

```
                         0
  match                   
1 0           CV Submitted
  1       Feedback Pending
  2       Client CV Review
  3      Feedback Awaiting
2 0           CV Submitted
  1       Feedback Pending
  2            Interview 1
  3              Scheduled
```

The regex pattern `'<strong>(.+?)</strong>'` will match everything between `<strong>` and `</strong>`, with little text as possible. To know more about regex, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/regex.html).